# Simplicial complexes are to PL structures of manifolds as simplicial sets are to what?

Tags: ct.category-theory, manifolds, simplicial-complexes

A simplicial complex is a PL structure for, and thus also homeomorphic to, a manifold if the link of every vertex is a simplicial sphere, for which there exists a definition. (I know that for high dimension, the definition might be untractable to check.) My question now is the same for simplicial *sets*.

Take for example the simplicial set with one vertex and one nondegenerate edge starting and ending at the vertex. Obviously, the geometrical realisation is $S^1$, but the link of the vertex is empty. In this case, the definition for a simplicial manifold fails.

I would be especially interested in a categorical definition, that is, one in terms of the simplicial set as a functor without much reference to its components.

Edit: I've clarified the question after a few years.

Comment: Your first sentence is false - there are simplicial complexes that are homeomorphic to manifolds but which contain vertices whose links are not spheres.  Google the "double suspension theorem" for examples.

Comment: I see, I ran into an intricacy here which I'm actually not interested in. Is it true that every simplicial complex that comes from a PL-manifold has a sphere as a link? Anyways, I've changed it to an "if" as opposed to an "iff", since the actual question is actually about simplicial sets.

Comment: Yes, PL triangulations of manifolds always have spheres as links.

Comment: The fact that in your $S^1$ example the link of the vertex is empty suggests that the "problem" is that you are using the "wrong" definition of link.

Comment: The link of a point in an $S^1$ should be an $S^0$, which is two distinct points. But there are no distinct points in my example, only one point, and that's the one we'd like to take the link of. That's why I doubt that one can improve on the definition of link. I was wondering whether there is a way to triangulate the simplicial set further until it is a simplicial complex, and then use the standard criterion...

Comment: Applying the barycentric subdivision functor twice produces a simplicial set that comes from a simplicial complex.  One can then apply the usual criterion with links of vertices.

Comment: Sounds plausible. Can you prove it?